# Python a way to mask two array with different dtype (unit 8 and unit16)

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, numpy

I have 2 arrays:

mask: with value 0 and 1, dtype=uint8

```
>>> mask
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ..., 
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

and prova_clip

```
>>> prova_clip
array([[289, 281, 271, ..., 257, 255, 255],
       [290, 284, 268, ..., 260, 260, 259],
       [294, 283, 264, ..., 265, 263, 257],
       ..., 
       [360, 359, 360, ..., 335, 338, 331],
       [359, 364, 369, ..., 337, 342, 339],
       [358, 363, 368, ..., 332, 331, 332]], dtype=uint16)
```

I wish to use a code saving method to mask prova_clip with mask in order to have

```
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [294, 283, 264, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ..., 
       [360, 359, 360, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint16)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Am I missing something?  This seems as simple as:

```
prova_clip*mask
```

Here's an example:

```
>>> a = np.arange(10,dtype=np.uint16)
>>> mask = np.ones(10,dtype=np.uint8)
>>> mask[1:3] = 0
>>> a*mask
array([0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=uint16)
```

---

You could also do it the complicated way which will modify an array in place.

```
>>> b = np.arange(10,dypte=np.uint16)
>>> b[~mask.astype(bool)] = 0
>>> b
array([0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=uint16)
```

---

Finally, there's `numpy.where`:

```
>>> c = np.arange(10,dtype=np.uint8)
>>> np.where(mask==0,0,c)
array([0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=uint16)
```

Comment: sorry for the disturb and Thanks. yes it was easy but after a long Friday i am exhausted, and easy stuff look hard in the late night.